# C# WCF REST Service Response - remove autogenerated content

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, response

I've created a RESTful service which provides the following response:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">hello</string>
```

However, I want it to only return 'hello'.  How can I do this?

interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IApp
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "/ourapi/v1/admin/certificate")]
    string retrieveInfo();
}
```

C#:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class App : IApp
{
    public string retrieveInfo()
    {
        WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;

        var dateValue = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string merchantId = "1234567";
        string errorCodeValue = "00";

        ctx.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("date", dateValue);
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("merchant-id", merchantId);
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("error-code", errorCodeValue);

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly stating the ResponseFormat to be XML in the service contract. What are your other options there?

Comment: @wgraham XML or JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have always done it is to return a `Stream`.  I also removed your request and response and set `BodyStyle` to Bare.

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    Method = "GET",
    UriTemplate = "/ourapi/v1/admin/certificate")]
Stream retrieveInfo();


[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class App : IApp
{
    public Stream retrieveInfo()
    {
        WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;

        var dateValue = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string merchantId = "1234567";
        string errorCodeValue = "00";

        ctx.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("date", dateValue);
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("merchant-id", merchantId);
        ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("error-code", errorCodeValue);

        return New System.IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can have response format of two type `XML` and `JSON`. But you can extend `WCF` to produce what you want. See the [article](http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.com/2013/02/wcf-rest-custom-webmessageformat.html) for more details